# datatables server side only working at localhost

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have problem with datatables server side at my server. There no data showing on my table. When I check console, show this error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at...

But on my localhost, data showing on my table. I followed the instruction here 
https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

here my javascript code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "scrollX": true,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "<?php echo $path; ?>ajax/server_processing.php"
    } );
} );
</script>
```

server_processing.php

```
<?php

/*
 * DataTables example server-side processing script.
 *
 * Please note that this script is intentionally extremely simply to show how
 * server-side processing can be implemented, and probably shouldn't be used as
 * the basis for a large complex system. It is suitable for simple use cases as
 * for learning.
 *
 * See http://datatables.net/usage/server-side for full details on the server-
 * side processing requirements of DataTables.
 *
 * @license MIT - http://datatables.net/license_mit
 */

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * Easy set variables
 */

// DB table to use
$table = 'data';

// Table's primary key
$primaryKey = 'id';

// Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
// The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
// parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
// indexes
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'scanning_timestamp', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'kPPCustomerFirstName',  'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'kPPCustomerFamilyName', 'dt' => 2),
    array( 'db' => 'kPPDateOfBirth',  'dt' => 3),
    array( 'db' => 'kPPHeightCm',   'dt' => 4 ),
    array( 'db' => 'kPPWeightKilograms',     'dt' => 5 ),
    array( 'db' => 'kPPCustomerMiddleName', 'dt' => 6 ),
    array( 'db' => 'kPPCustomerIdNumber',  'dt' => 7 ),
    array( 'db' => 'kPPOrganDonor',   'dt' => 8 ),
    array( 'db' => 'kPPWeightPounds',     'dt' => 9 ),
    array( 'db' => 'kPPAamvaVersionNumber', 'dt' => 10 ),
    array( 'db' => 'kPPHeight',  'dt' => 11 ),
    array( 'db' => 'kPPIssuerIdentificationNumber',   'dt' => 12 ),
    array( 'db' => 'kPPDocumentIssueDate',     'dt' => 13 ),
    array( 'db' => 'kPPAddressJurisdictionCode',  'dt' => 14 ),
    array( 'db' => 'kPPAddressStreet',   'dt' => 15 ),
    array( 'db' => 'kPPNonResident',     'dt' => 16 ),
    array( 'db' => 'kPPJurisdictionVehicleClass', 'dt' => 17 ),
    array( 'db' => 'kPPIssuingJurisdiction',  'dt' => 18 ),
    array( 'db' => 'kPPDocumentExpirationDate',   'dt' => 19 ),
    array( 'db' => 'kPPIssueTimestamp',     'dt' => 20 ),
    array( 'db' => 'kPPAddressCity', 'dt' => 21 ),
    array( 'db' => 'kPPHairColor',  'dt' => 22 ),
    array( 'db' => 'kPPHeightIn',   'dt' => 23 ),
    array( 'db' => 'kPPSex',     'dt' => 24 ),
    array( 'db' => 'kPPJurisdictionRestrictionCodes', 'dt' => 25 ),
    array( 'db' => 'kPPEyeColor',  'dt' => 26 ),
    array( 'db' => 'kPPJurisdictionVersionNumber',   'dt' => 27 ),
    array( 'db' => 'kPPCustomerFullName',     'dt' => 28 ),
    array( 'db' => 'kPPAddressPostalCode', 'dt' => 29 )
);

// SQL server connection information
$sql_details = array(
    'user' => 'root',
    'pass' => '',
    'db'   => 'bowen',
    'host' => 'localhost'
);


/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP
 * server-side, there is no need to edit below this line.
 */

require( 'ssp.class.php' );

echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
```

for ssp.class.php same as in https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

*sorry if my english is not good

Comment: please show where each thing is hosted.

Comment: you mean my website hosting?

Comment: yea what origin is the javascript running on and what origin the service is running on.

Comment: no what origin (urls).

Comment: ah sorry, you mean my website url? here http://bowenverification.com/

Comment: @DanielA.White how to solve my problem?

Comment: nevermind. I'm already fix it